# TikZ - accurate colors with shifting in scope environments while using transparency group and opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

Is it possible to display identical images accurately without color change when the options  `[transparency group]` and `[opacity]` are used and the images are stacked on top of each other while shifted in scope environments?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
\node[rounded corners=20mm,fill=red,minimum size=4cm] {} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5, xshift=5mm, yshift=5mm]
\node[rounded corners=20mm,fill=red,minimum size=4cm] {} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm]
\node[rounded corners=20mm,fill=red,minimum size=4cm] {} ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your nodes have the same color, but since they are overlap, in the overlap areas due to used transparency are visible color of covered nodes. What you expect to get? BTW, you use quite unusual l way to draw circles ....

Comment: BTW, the same results as with your MWE you can get with the following much simpler and shorter code: \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{positioning}  \begin{document}     \begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance = 5mm and 5mm, on grid,      N/.style = {circle, minimum size=4cm, fill=red, opacity=0.5,                  node contents={}}                         ] \node (n1) [N]; \node (n2) [N, above right=of n1]; \node (n3) [N, above right=of n2];     \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}

Comment: Like @Zarko, I'm curious what you expect if you stack semi-transparent things on top of each other. If you don't want to see circles (circle-squares?) 1 and 2 through 3, put them all in a single transparency group. Then Ti*k*Z will apply `opacity=.5` to everything inside the scope at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encouraged by @cfr answer (+1), let me extend my comment to an answer:

- a case, then all circles has the same color (this is easy, just remove `opacity=0.5` options):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 5mm, on grid,
     N/.style = {circle, minimum size=4cm, fill=red!50, 
                 node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N];
\node (n2) [N, above right=of n1];
\node (n3) [N, above right=of n2];
\node (n4) [N, above right=of n3];
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- A case, that you like to see circles covered by other circles, and see their color, you need to add transparency to nodes, for example by `opacity=0.5. In this case compilation result is as you show in question:

[image]

For this you not need to use `transparency group`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 5mm, on grid,
     N/.style = {circle, minimum size=4cm, fill=red, opacity=0.5,
                 node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N];
\node (n2) [N, above right=of n1];
\node (n3) [N, above right=of n2];
\node (n4) [N, above right=of n3];
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're entirely right: of course just changing the base colour is much simpler than a transparency group!

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you want a result which is not expected if you stack transparent objects, but rather what is expected if you apply transparency to an irregular shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% shamelessly borrowing Zarko's code to avoid trying vainly to square circles (or circle squares?) at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694688/tikz-accurate-colors-with-shifting-in-scope-environments-while-using-transpare#comment1724430_694688
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance = 5mm and 5mm, on grid, N/.style = {circle, minimum size=4cm, fill=red, node contents={}} ]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.5]
    \node (n1) [N]; \node (n2) [N, above right=of n1]; \node (n3) [N, above right=of n2]; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: effect of transparency group]